# Symfony API Platform - embed insert

Tags: api, symfony, platform

I have entity Users, related to Addresses

```
    /**
 * @Groups({"users:read","users:write"})
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Addresses", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist"},orphanRemoval=true)
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $addresses;
```

When I try to insert an addreess on update (from Postman):

```
{
"phoneNumber": "98893",
"completedValues": {
    "fieldId":4,
    "elementId":25
}
```

}

I have the following error:

```
"hydra:description": "The type of the key \"fieldId\" must be \"int\", \"string\" given.",
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. completedValues should be an array

{
"phoneNumber": "98893",
"completedValues": [{
    "fieldId":4,
    "elementId":25
}]